# Open XML not saving when adding data C#

Tags: c#, excel, sdk, openxml

I did a complete copy from the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd452407(v=office.12).aspx

The copy from template works fine, the `FixChartData()` method works fine. However, the output File does not contain any data. I do see that the contentRow contains the data via the debugger, but the excel sheet does not have the data in it when I open the file.

Very frustrating. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void Create()
    {
        string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));

        string templateFile = appPath + @"\Templates\ChartExample.xlsx";
        string saveFile = appPath + @"\Documents\Generated.xlsx";



        File.Copy(templateFile, saveFile, true);

        //open copied template.
        using(SpreadsheetDocument myWorkbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(saveFile, true))
        {
            //this is the workbook contains all the worksheets
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart;

            //we know that the first worksheet contains the data for the graph
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First(); //getting the first worksheet
            //the shhet data contains the information we are looking to alter
            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

            int index = 2;//Row the data for the graph starts on
            //var qry = from t in db.SEL_SE_DEATHS()
            FudgeData fudge = new FudgeData();

            var qry = fudge.Fudged();

            foreach(var item in qry)
            {
                int Year = item.EventYear;
                int PSQ = item.PSQReviewable;
                int death = item.Deaths;

                Row contentRow = CreateContentRow(index, Year, PSQ, death);
                index++;
                //contentRow.RowIndex = (UInt32)index;
                sheetData.AppendChild(contentRow);

            }

            //(<x:c r="A2" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><x:v>2014</x:v></x:c><x:c r="B2" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><x:v>21</x:v></x:c><x:c r="C2" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><x:v>4</x:v></x:c>)
            FixChartData(workbookPart, index);
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

            myWorkbook.Close();
            myWorkbook.Dispose();
        }

    }

    string[] headerColumns = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" }; //the columns being accessed
    public Row CreateContentRow(int index, int year, int pSQ, int death)
    {
        Row r = new Row();
        r.RowIndex = (UInt32)index;

        //skipping the text add function

        //we are createing a cell for each column (headerColumns),
        //for each cell we are adding a value.
        //we then append the value to the cell and append the cell to the row - wich is returned.
        for(int i =0; i <headerColumns.Length; i++)
        {
            Cell c = new Cell();
            c.CellReference = headerColumns[i] + index;
            CellValue v = new CellValue();
            if(i == 0)
            {
                v.Text = year.ToString();
            }else if(i == 1)
            {
                v.Text = pSQ.ToString();
            }else if(i == 2)
            {
                v.Text = death.ToString();
            }
            c.AppendChild(v);
            r.AppendChild(c);
        }
        return r;

    }

    //Method for when the datatype is text based
    public Cell CreateTextCell(string header, string text, int index)
    {
        //Create a new inline string cell.
        Cell c = new Cell();
        c.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;
        c.CellReference = header + index;
        //Add text to the text cell.
        InlineString inlineString = new InlineString();
        Text t = new Text();
        t.Text = text;
        inlineString.AppendChild(t);
        c.AppendChild(inlineString);
        return c;
    }

    //fix the chart Data Regions
    public void FixChartData(WorkbookPart workbookPart, int totalCount)
    {

        var wsparts = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.ToArray();

        foreach(WorksheetPart wsp in wsparts)
        {
            if(wsp.DrawingsPart != null)
            {
                ChartPart chartPart = wsp.DrawingsPart.ChartParts.First();
                ////change the ranges to accomodate the newly inserted data.
                foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Formula formula in chartPart.ChartSpace.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Formula>())
                {
                    if (formula.Text.Contains("$2"))
                    {
                        string s = formula.Text.Split('$')[1];
                        formula.Text += ":$" + s + "$" + totalCount;
                    }
                }
                chartPart.ChartSpace.Save();
            }
        }

        //ChartPart chartPart = workbookPart.ChartsheetParts.First().DrawingsPart.ChartParts.First();
        ////change the ranges to accomodate the newly inserted data.
        //foreach(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Formula formula in chartPart.ChartSpace.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Formula>())
        //{
        //    if (formula.Text.Contains("$2"))
        //    {
        //        string s = formula.Text.Split('$')[1];
        //        formula.Text += ":$" + s + "$" + totalCount;
        //    }
        //}
        //chartPart.ChartSpace.Save();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David,
I got your code to work fine.  [Here is a link to my Console Application.](https://github.com/thomasbtatum/SO-42704376).   I uploaded it to Github with some minor changes.  I made 2 changes:

1)  I was not able to download the samples from the link you provided.  So I created a blank empty spreadsheet with Excel2016 and saved it in that directory.

2)  The Fudge data was missing, so I generated some sample data via self mocked object.

The spreadsheet copies fine from the template and your code populates it with the fudge data.  Here is what the final result looks like:

[image]

After downloading, you will need to make a `Template` and `Document` subdirectory.  Then place my `ChartExample.xslx` file in the Template directory and run.

Comment: why OP's code not work?